# Assign Value to function,why we are not able to assign the value to function when it return the value but in case of reference and pointers it works?

Tags: c, function, pointers, return, function-pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

int function  (){

    int a  = 10; 
    return a; //Here we are return the value 
}

int main()
{

function() = 3;//And here we assign the value 3 to return value then why it causes error 
               

}
```

Comment: You invoke functions, passing information 'in', and perhaps receiving a result 'out'. If the task is to store the value 3, then `int value = 3` is the way to do it...

Answer (score 3):

The call to function() evaluates to 10, so the assignment in your main() function evaluates to:

10 = 3;

10 is not an lvalue, hence you cannot assign to it.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>

int *function (){
    int a  = 10;
    return &a;
}
int main(){

*function() = 3;//but in case pointers how it is possible to assign ?


}

Comment: @anonymous The compiler is not required to warn you that the pointer doesn't point to anything anymore. But it's legal because when you dereference the pointer, you get an lvalue.

Comment: In you second example, the function doesn't return an int, it returns a pointer, i.e. the address of the variable "a". Dereferencing the pointer is an lvalue, i.e. you can assign to it.  However, in your case "a" is a local variable which exists only while you're in the function, so it's a bad idea to return a pointer to it. The compiler will give you a warning about that.

Comment: @anonymous your `int a` is an automatic variable, local to the function. Because it lives on the stack only during execution of the function, returning its address is a bug. If you want to assign '3' to a variable within a function, pass it as a parameter. `function( 3 );`

Answer (score 1):

In C, it is not avaliable to have function names on the left side of an expression.

But you can try it by using C++, it will work!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int &fun() {
  static int x;
  return x;
}

int main() {
  fun() = 10;

  // this line will print 10
  printf(" %d \n", fun());

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The above code works for two reasons (apart from being C++ and not C) : 1. fun() returns a reference to "x", i.e. a modifiable location in memory. 2. "x" is declared as "static" which makes it of "static storage duration", i.e. it keeps existing even when fun() exits.

Answer (score 0):

The `function()` is a function, not a variable.The variable cannot be assigned to a function in c language.

Comment: In the question `function()` is not just a function, it is a function call (which returns a value.  In the question a literal value is being assigned rather than a variable.  The real problem here is that a value cannot be assigned to a value.